# how to open & use cakephp i18n console?

Tags: cakephp, console

how to open & use cakephp i18n console ????s

Answer (score 0):

What operating system are you using?

In Linux, open your shell and navigate to the app directory of the application you're working on. If everything is correctly configured, you just run `$ cake i18n` and follow the instructions. If it's not, you need to run cake.php with the PHP executable `$ /usr/bin/php -q -f ../cake/libs/console/cake.php i18n`.

It's the same in windows, just the paths and executable name are different. It looks like `C:\www\project\app> c:\php\bin\php.exe -q -f c:\www\project\cake\libs\console\cake.php i18n`.